# Disc brake keeps making ping-like shudder

Tags: repair, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, commuting-bike

I have a commuter bike with Tektro MD-285 hydraulic disc brakes. I commute about 14 miles every day (7 in, 7 out) in most types of weather, but I am not a performance cyclist by any means. It's just a good way to get to work. For the past few months, I have had a bit of a squeal and a shuddering noise that I can feel through the handlebars on the front brake when I brake it hard. When slower there is really little to no noise. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on. Here is what I have tried:

- Sanding down and cleaning new pads and rotor.
- Getting new pads and rotor and going through the bed-in process.
- After replacing, pushing the pistons back in on the brake to try to ensure they are parallel and the whole pad is hitting the rotor.
- Made sure the headset was not too loose.
- Checked the AL fork for any cracks.

Any other ideas? Worth bleeding the brakes?

Comment: From my limited experience of hydraulics this isn't the sort of thing bleeding helps with. Is everything tight? Is there any weather dependence? Is the new rotor the same as the old one (the Shimano rotor on my dynamo wheel causes a little vibration while the promax on my original wheel doesn't; cable discs on that bike)? When I get a more musical sound (either bike with discs) it's normally a bit of grit in the caliper housing.

Comment: There is no weather dependence; it is the same rain or shine, and in warm or cold weather. Everything seems to be tight too and the calipers seem centered. The replacement is  a Tektro rotor with the same hole pattern and also Tektro pads. The brake does not feel soft, so I wouldn't think bleeding would work, but I'm at a loss. Could there be gunk on the pistons preventing one from coming out flat with the rotor? The noise almost sounds like a corner or edge of the brake pad hitting the holes of the rotor.

Comment: Check your front wheel for loose spokes and cracks in the rim, especially around all the spoke holes.

Comment: Do you have a friend with a wheel that you can fit in your bike? If you find that using a different wheel and rotor fixes the issue, then you know where your issue is. If it doesn't, then you've at least ruled those two things out.

Comment: Those are both great suggestions. I forgot to mention that I recently bought a new wheel because the bearings were rusted out, and the hub is supposed to be "non-servicable". The hub is a sanyo/panasonic dynohub, but with a 6-bolt disc attachment, and I couldn't buy the hub by itself anywhere. The problem exists with both wheels, and even after putting a new rotor on the new wheel. It seems like the only thing left is the caliper, no?

Comment: My hub and rotor combo is super sensitive to position. If I place the calliper in exactly the correct position, the edge of the calliper lightly clips the rotor with a musical plunka, plunka sound.  To correct I center the calliper just off ( circa 0.25 mm) . To fix I guess I would need to get the hub rotor bolt holes lightly faced by a LBS to strip away a tiny bit of material. I won’t bother but possibly you have a similar issue.

Comment: Are you talking about a little wobble in the rotor causing a scrape on the pad every so often when the brakes aren't actuated, or does the sound you describe happen when the brakes are pulled? I think the rotor is fairly true already, as in I can position the calipers so there is basically no rub when the wheel is spun. Has anyone needed a rotor more true than that to avoid noises?

Comment: Maybe not so dumb question, Have you checked that the caliper bolt are tight? Once had my bike sound like a bus when breaking, turned out to be just a loose caliper. Other time it was the rotor that was loose, and it was a centerlock rotor.

Comment: Thanks! It has unfortunately persisted through a number of recenterings of the caliper where I tightened it back up. On the other hand, I hadn't fully tightened them once and the noise and shake was a lot worse!

Comment: Welp, I took the pads off and took another look. The outside piston seemed stuck, so I tried to clean both the pistons with some string and alcohol and they both seem to come out now. I wonder if the outer piston was seized and the pad a little crooked, leading to the noise. But of course, I figured I'd do the same to the rear brake and then noticed that fluid is leaking from it. So no idea if it worked until that is fixed, but hopefully I will see soon!

Comment: Still no luck with cleaned pistons, so the only thing I can think of is a new caliper. Hopefully that will do it.

Comment: I had an issue very much like this (rear brake on a BMC 29er) - the bike shop had bike 3 weeks trying to resolve it.  After trying new pads, new rotor etc etc, it was eventually solved by greasing the caliper bolts.  This solution makes no sense to anyone, but it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Replaced the brake and all is well. My guess is one side of a piston was being pushed out with more force than another.